# How to use the colloquial "vrai de vrai"?

Tags: sens, usage

My friend just said in conversation:

> Vrai de vrai.

I suppose it boils down to saying "Comme c'est vrai !" or something, but how emphatic does "vrai de vrai" sound?

Incidentally, there is a French restaurant in Japan called "vrai de vrai". I wonder if in this case, "truly authentic" is its intended meaning?

Is it possible to use other adjectives than "vrai" and say "adjective + de + adjective"?

Comment: It's like kosher truth or something.

Comment: I think it's only used, either to emphasise or to confirm a previously observed truth: « C'est un (vrai) idiot. Un vrai de vrai. » or « — Tu connais vraiment Lionel Messi personnellement ? — Oui. Vrai de vrai. ». But it definitively can't be used with any other adjective.

Answer (score 3):

It means "really, I swear it's true !" It sounds both a bit childish and old-fashioned, but not that much.

For a restaurant it sounds a bit random but your interpretation can be correct. That's not the weirdest name for a restaurant in Japan I heard of.

For other adjectives you can't use the same form but it works if you add "chez":

> Je suis crevé de chez crevé. -> I am very tired.

It looks less childish and old-fashioned but more familiar that "vrai de vrai".

Answer (score 0):

It's a noun. "Un vrai de vrai" un vrai mec, un dur, un authentique, a machoman. I think it's Pègre slang, so it can sound a bit outdated.